# Possible to use assert in C++ , displaying classname::function ( param ) in detail?

Tags: c++, gcc, assert

Is it possible to get class name , and the parameter of that function , whiling using assert ?

For now i only tried `__FUNCTION__` which display only the name of function.

Is it possible to display `Dummy::Func ( int param1 )` rather than `Func` ?

I'm expecting a solution of g++ compiler , thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On GCC at least, there is `__PRETTY_FUNCTION__`, which does about what you ask.

But it's not a preprocessor macro, and so likely won't be expanded as you might want inside an assert().  Of course, neither will `__FUNCTION__` unless you're using a fairly old version of G++.

Comment: +1 on `__pretty_function__`, that is as good as you can get (and apart from the new C++0x `__func__` it's not any less portable than anything else). Do note that gcc thinks that function name macros are not constant expressions (this usually does not matter, but it does in some situations -- for example if like me you believe being super smart and use `__pretty_function__` with a `constexpr` hash for your own RTTI system, this gives a nasty surprise).